# MasterDetail ListView and editable ContentPresenter: what is wrong?

Tags: xaml, listview, binding, uwp, master-detail

I'm based on the official Microsoft sample to create a **MasterDetail ListView**:
[MasterDetail ListView UWP sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlListView)

I have adapted it to my case, as I want that users can **edit directly selected items from the ListView**. But I meet a strange comportement:

- when I **add a new item** to the ListView, the changes of the current item, done in the details container, are **well saved**
- but when I **select an existing item** in the ListView, the changes of the current item, done in the details container, are **not saved**

Here is a screenshot of my app:
[image: screenshot]

The XAML of my **ListView** is like this:

```
<!-- Master : List of Feedbacks -->
<ListView
    x:Name="MasterListViewFeedbacks"
    Grid.Row="1"
    ItemContainerTransitions="{x:Null}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MasterListViewFeedbacksItemTemplate}"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CarForm.feedback_comments}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFeedback, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.FooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CommandBar Background="White">
                <CommandBar.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add Feedback"
                                  Command="{Binding AddItemFeedbacksCommand}" />
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Delete Feedback"
                                  Command="{Binding RemoveItemFeedbacksCommand}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </CommandBar.Content>
            </CommandBar>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.FooterTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The XAML of the **ListView's ItemTemplate** is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MasterListViewFeedbacksItemTemplate" x:DataType="models:Feedback_Comments">
    <StackPanel Margin="0,11,0,13"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind creator }" 
                   Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" />
        <TextBlock Text=" - " />
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind comment_date }"
                   Margin="12,1,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The XAML of the **Details container** is like this:

```
<!-- Detail : Selected Feedback -->
<ContentPresenter
    x:Name="DetailFeedbackContentPresenter"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    BorderThickness="1,0,0,0"
    Padding="24,0"
    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}"
    Content="{x:Bind MasterListViewFeedbacks.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Feedback_Comments">
            <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding FeedbacksCnt, Converter={StaticResource CountToVisibilityConverter}}">

                <TextBox Text="{Binding creator, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <DatePicker Date="{Binding comment_date, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"
                         Text="{Binding comment, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTransitions>
        <!-- Empty by default. See MasterListView_ItemClick -->
        <TransitionCollection />
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTransitions>
</ContentPresenter>
```

The "**CarForm**" is the main object of my ViewModel. Each CarForm contains a List of "**Feedback_Comments**".

So in my **ViewModel**, I do this when I add a **new comment**:

```
private void AddItemFeedbacks()
{
    FeedbacksCnt++;
    CarForm.feedback_comments.Add(new Feedback_Comments()
    {
        sequence = FeedbacksCnt,
        creator_id = user_id,
        _creator = username,
        comment_date = DateTime.Now
    });
    SelectedFeedback = CarForm.feedback_comments[CarForm.feedback_comments.Count - 1];
}
```

***=> the changes done in the Feedback_Comment that was edited before the add are well preserved***

I don't do anything when the user select an existing Feedback_Comment: this is managed by the XAML directly.

***=> the changes done in the Feedback_Comment that was edited before to select anoter one are not preserved***

***=> Would you have any explanation?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TwoWay` binding for the `Text` property is updated only when the `TextBox` loses focus. However, when you select a different item in the list, the contents of the `TextBox` are no longer bound to the original item and so are not updated.

To trigger the update each time the `Text` contents change, so that the changes are reflected immediately, set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` set to `PropertyChanged`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding comment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

## Triggering changes everywhere

To ensure your changes are relflected everywhere including the list, you will need to do two things.

First, your `feedback_comments` is of type `ObservableCollection<Feedback_Comments>`. This ensures that the added and removed items are added and removed from the `ListView`.

Second, the `Feedback_Comments` class must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. This interface is required to let the user interface know about changes in the data-bound object properties.

Implementing this interface is fairly straightforward and is described [for example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.110).aspx).

The quick solution looks like this:

```cs
public class Feedback_Comments : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    // your code

    //INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged( [ CallerMemberName ]string propertyName = "" )
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
}
```

Now from each of your property setters call `OnPropertyChanged();` after setting the value:

```cs
private string _comment = "";
public string Comment
{
   get
   {
       return _comment;
   }
   set
   {
       _comment = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Note, that the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute tells the compiler to replace the parameter by the name of the caller - in this case the name of the property, which is exactly what you need.

Also note, that you can't use simple auto-properties in this case (because you need to call the `OnPropertyChanged` method.

### Bonus

Finally as a small recommendation, I see you are using C++-like naming conventions, which does not fit too well into the C# world. Take a look at the [recommended C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040(v=vs.110).aspx) to improve the code readability :-) .

Comment: Thank you @Martin Zikmund, it's better like this: the changes in the fields are well preserved if I select another item.
But is there a way to update too the fields in the "Master" ListView?
It's not the same binding ("{x:Bind xxx}") and I'm not familiar with this, so I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the solution to this problem and a small tip :-)

Comment: Hi Martin,
I tried your last solution but it doesn't work for me.
Isn't it due to the fact that the DataTemplate uses {x:Bind} ?

Comment: Or maybe it's the relationship between the List (MasterListViewFeedbacks) and the Details (DetailFeedbackContentPresenter): Content="{x:Bind MasterListViewFeedbacks.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"